# iOS side scrolling graphic novel

Tags: ios, image, swift

If you read this:

Don't do what I did, use a `UICollectionView`

---

A friend made a graphic novel that is essentially one very long continuous drawing. In book form it is separated in pages, but he asked me if it were possible to make it into an app.
Not that I am a genius iOS developer, but i got my feet a little damp.

So my basic idea was to make a side scrolling "game" with just a background. This would make it possible to load the slides when needed, save reading position,....

Since I am new at this and I know no objective c (only swift) I am having trouble figuring out how to make a scrollable scene.

Apple has some sample code in objective c explaining the world/camera/scene set up. But this incomplete.

All i need is a way to drag the background to the left and right. Any help on this would be super awesome!

update 2 This works! sort of....  Problem is, that it doesnt scroll, it just move the world to the point of touch. Any help would still be awesome!:

```
import SpriteKit

class CameraScene : SKScene {
    // Flag indicating whether we've setup the camera system yet.
    var isCreated: Bool = false
    // The root node of your game world. Attach game entities
    // (player, enemies, &c.) to here.
    var world: SKNode?
    // The root node of our UI. Attach control buttons & state
    // indicators here.
    var overlay: SKNode?
    // The camera. Move this node to change what parts of the world are visible.
    var camera: SKNode?




    var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        if !isCreated {
            isCreated = true

            // Camera setup
            self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            self.camera = SKNode()
            self.camera?.name = "world"
            addChild(self.camera!)
            self.world = SKNode()
            self.world?.name = "camera"
            self.camera?.addChild(self.world!)
            self.world?.addChild(SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "bg_1"))


            // UI setup
            self.overlay = SKNode()
            self.overlay?.zPosition = 10
            self.overlay?.name = "overlay"
            addChild(self.overlay!)
        }
    }


    func moveWorld () {
        world?.position = CGPointMake((location.x), 0)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        var touch : UITouch! = touches.anyObject() as UITouch

        location = touch.locationInView(self.view)



        moveWorld()

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to invent the wheel (especially if you are new to the plattform!)

Set up a UICollectionView and allow it to scroll horizontally. Make the datasource return image names that are your book pages. And you are (almost) done!

Here is something that seems to explain something similar (although in Objective C):
http://devblog.orgsync.com/2013/04/26/creating_scrolling_filmstrip_within_uitableview/

Comment: Not that bookmarking would be hard to implement using a UICollectionView but may be you have other reasons not to use it.

Comment: About your SpriteKit thing. You basically need to implement touchesBegan and save the location of the touch. Then in touchesMoved you need to diff that to the current touch position and move the world accordingly. Try searching for SpriteKit drag implementation.